# LZW in matlab how can I put the image to the LZW algorithm

Tags: matlab, lzw

Thank you in advance for you help, my question is 
I am doing LZW compression in Matlab , I choose the image through a selection dialog box then I read the image by `imread` command after that I do not know what to do or how to do what I have is the LZW algorithm but how to refer the image to that algorithm, this is my try which is wrong my problem after `imread` what I should put to reach LZW_Encoding algorithm and how can I store the data after the compression

```
[filename pathname] = uigetfile({'*.tiff';'*.bmp'},'File Selector');
image=strcat(pathname,filename);
pic=imread(image);
[output,table] = LZW_Encoding(uint8(pic));
fid = fopen('EN_Lzw.txt','w');
fprintf(fid,'%c',output);
fclose(fid);
```

Regards 
Wadoo

LZW_Encoding is an open source function and my problem is not in the LZW function but how to refer the image to it and how to write the text file the encoded one

```
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4899-lzw-compression-algorithm/content/lzw2norm.m
```

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4899-lzw-compression-algorithm/content/norm2lzw.m

Comment: how is LZW_Encoding implemented?

Comment: What problems did you encounter using the above code?

Comment: the LZW_Encoding input variable which is (uint8(pic)) is wrong I should put a vector which represent the image

Answer (score -1):

Try using the following code:

```
pic=rgb2gray(pic);
[m, n]=size(pic);
pictmp=reshape(bw',1,m*n);
```

Then apply LZW function to pictmp.